# no VT driver in linux /proc/tty/drivers

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, tty

I was trying to access a VT (e.g. /dev/tty1) on my android phone (Xiaomi Mi MIX, Lithium) when i noticed that the device file wasn't there, so i created it with `mknod /dev/tty1 c 4 1` and then tried to access it with both of busybox's `chvt` and `openvt` which gave me and error saying `No such device or address`

This made me feel like VTs were disabled in the kernel, and i ran `cat /proc/tty/drivers` and noticed that there was no driver for major 4 minor 1-63. So, being pretty inexperienced with the kernel i'm wondering how i can add a tty drivers. Do i have to recompile the kernel and set som flag to enable ttys? Or can i enable it permanently or temporarily after booting the system?

tl;dr
How can i enable VT drivers? Do i have to recompile kernel?

Comment: I browser the lithium source code and i can see that CONFIG_VT and CONFIG_TTY are unset by default and those are used to compile the tty driver. So i probably have to compile a custom kernel, unless someone else has a better solution.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange](http://android.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: I posted it here since i was expecting that i most likely have to recompile the kernel and make some changes to make it compile with VT support. Also programmers familiar with the kernel are probably most likely to know the answer to this.

Answer (score 0):

After going through the source code and double checking with documentation references i'm sure that i have to recompile the kernel. The flags CONFIG_VT and CONFIG_TTY have to be set, which they are not in most modern android kernels. When doing this, i found that version 3.18 doesn't really play nice with gcc>4.9 and that there were multiple include path errors which had to be resolved.